# Making a text box that duplicates upon input in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to make a series of text boxes. It starts with one text box, but when the user puts information into it, another empty text box appears beneath it. This continues indefinitely.

Each text box needs to have an `ng-model` value associated with it, and each needs to be generated by `ng-repeat`.

For example, my HTML is this:

```
<table ng-controller="BoxesController">
  <tr ng-repeat="box in boxes">
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="box.input"></td> <!--boxes[0].input-->
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm using `box.input` rather than just `box` because it needs to have other variables assigned to it as well.

Then my controller would be:

```
.controller('BoxesController',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.boxes = [
    {input: ""}
  ];

  if($scope.boxes[$scope.boxes.length - 1] !== ""){
    $scope.boxes.push({input: ""});
    $scope.$apply;
  }
}])
```

This would create an empty box in the view in which `box.input === ""`. The `if` is basically *"If the last value in the array is not empty, append a new empty value to the array."*

This whole thing should, initially, create a single empty box then generate more boxes as the user inputs data box by box.

However, what it actually does is generate two empty boxes that do not respond to input at all.

Would anyone know what to do here, how to make this work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the condition within a method:

```
$scope.newBox = function() {
   if($scope.boxes[$scope.boxes.length - 1].input !== ""){
    $scope.boxes.push({input: ""});
    console.log( $scope.boxes)
    $scope.$apply;
  }
};
```

Html:

```
<td><input type="text" ng-model="box.input" ng-blur="newBox()"></td>
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/aLIdlztpNFKuoWVnNjIB?p=preview)

Comment: You probably meant `if($scope.boxes[$scope.boxes.length - 1].input !== "")`

Comment: @KKKKKKKK you found it!!

Comment: @Dev-One now the `ng-blur` in unusefull because the issue was elsewhere.

Comment: @morels, How so? If the last box has value it will create a new box else it will not.

Comment: it is not necessary any blur event nor function enclosure because the code of the user already functions, with @KKKKKKKK's fix

Comment: @morels, it would not. See this: https://plnkr.co/edit/Bsr5qaWytSF7H2aiPWrg?p=preview
OP would still need to `$watch` the `$scope.boxes` for pushing a new box.

Comment: Ooh, ngBlur, that's a new one. Thank you very much for this!

Answer (score 3):

As the answer above, try to use an method. Here another example using ng-change.

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('BoxesController',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.boxes = [
    {}
  ];
  
  $scope.callChange = function() {
    if($scope.boxes[$scope.boxes.length - 1].val !== ""){
      $scope.boxes.push({val: ""});
    }
  };  
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app'>
  <table ng-controller='BoxesController'>    
    <tr ng-repeat="box in boxes">
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="box.val" ng-change="callChange()"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```